# Prefix to Infix with minimum number of parenthesis using c language

Tags: c, stack, prefix, infix-operator

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
struct Stack
{
    char stk[50][50];
    int top;
};
typedef struct Stack stack;
void push(stack *p, char c)
{
    p->top++;
    p->stk[p->top][0] = c ;
    p->stk[p->top][1] = '\0';

}

void puush(stack *p, char val[])
{
    p->top++;
    int i=0 , len = strlen(val);
    for( i = 0; i< len ; i++)
        p->stk[p->top][i] = val[i];
    p->stk[p->top][i] = '\0';



}
void pop(stack *p)
{
    p->top--;
}
char *top(stack *p)
{
    return p->stk[p->top];
}
void print(stack *p)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(i <= p->top)
    {
        printf("index : %d elements : %s\n", i+1, p->stk[i]);
        i++;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
int isOperand(char c)
{
    if((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'))
        return 1;
    else return 0;
}
int isOperator(char c)
{
    switch(c)
    {
    case '+':
    case '-':
    case '*':
    case '/':
        return 1;
    default:
        return 0;
    }

}
void prefixToInfix(char s[])
{
    stack s1;
    s1.top = -1;
    int i=0, len = strlen(s) - 1;

    for(i = len ; i>= 0 ; i--)
    {
        if(isOperand(s[i]))
        {

            printf("%c\n\n",s[i]);
            push(&s1, s[i]);
            print(&s1);

        }

        if(isOperator(s[i]))
        {
            char concat[20];
            int k,j= -1;
            concat[++j] = '(';
            char *c1 = top(&s1);
            pop(&s1);
            int len1 = 0;
            len1 = strlen(c1);
            for(k=0; k<len1; k++)
            {
                concat[++j] = c1[k];
            }
            concat[++j] = s[i];
            c1 = top(&s1);
            len1 = strlen(c1);
            pop(&s1);
            for(k= 0; k<len1; k++)
                concat[++j] = c1[k];
            concat[++j]=')';
            concat[++j] = '\0';
            printf("gnerated %s\n",concat);
            puush(&s1, concat);
            print(&s1);
        }


    }
    printf("%s",top(&s1));


}
int main()
{
    prefixToInfix("*-A/BC-/AKL");

}
```

Please help me, I am not getting the correct output as it should be. I am sharing my code thus it will be easier for you all to understand the problem of my Code

**Explanation of my problem:**

I have been trying to write a code which converts The Prefix form to Infix. I am getting the output as I expected except one extra parenthesis at last:
For example:

```
                   The Input: "*-A/BC-/AKL"

                 Expected Output: ((A-(B/C))*((A/K)-L)
```

However my Program output:

```
             ((A-(B/C))*((A/K)-L)(, the last extra parenthesis is the issue "("
```

Comment: If it's supposed to produce the minimum number of parentheses, the output should be `(A-B/C)*(A/K-L)`

Comment: Here's the more important question, though. How many characters are there in `((A-(B/C))*((A/K)-L))`? You build that string in `concat`, which is `char concat[20];`. Will it fit? Where does your code check to make sure there is no buffer overrun?

Comment: Yes you are right.  Now I comprehend why this is showing wrong output.  Thank you so much for your response @rici. Take care